# I was sent a google form (link) and can see the senders answers

Tags: google-forms

I was just sent a link by a colleague to a google form. I can see that they ran a test of the form with "dummy' answers. Can the sender change this so that others don't see their responses in the form?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, it will depend on what kind of link the sender sent.

Google Forms has several kinds of links

1. Collaborate
2. Submit a response
3. Pre-filled response
4. Edit response url

On case 1, the sender can't block collaborators to see the responses.

On cases 2 to 4, a form could be set to allow respondents to see previous submitted responses. The sender, assuming that they is the owner or a collaborator (editor), they could turn off this option.

For details please checkout [Send your form people](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839588?hl=en)